# Microsoft Exchange WebService URL

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

How to know Exchange WebService URL, I have Exchange server version 2007 and I am trying to write a small C# console application to collect some data from exchange server but don't know what is the Exchange.WebServices Url. AutodiscoverUrl failed.

Comment: Did you add a web reference (or service reference) or are you going through the EWS Managed API?

Answer (score 8):

You can find the web service at

```
https://<myserver>/ews/exchange.asmx
```

You can find a tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/Exchange2007EWS-Part1.aspx

Comment: One minor adjustment:  By default, the EWS virtual directory requires SSL.  So you'll have to use HTTPS unless that was adjusted.

Comment: you can find XSD files at https://<myserver>/EWS/messages.xsd
https://<myserver>/EWS/types.xsd

Answer (score 2):

Go to your exchange server and open exchange management shell.

Run the command:

```
Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl *url
```

You will see two URL's: Internal and External (for every Exchange server in your organization).  I would be more concerned with why autodiscover is failing.  I'm guessing you're using an external client (non-domain joined) and you don't have AutoDiscover set up in your DNS.

If you cannot log into your Exchange server, it may be a bit more difficult with AutoDiscover not working, but it should be 'https://*server*/ews/exchange.asmx' (where *server* is the Fully Qualified Domain Name internally or the CAS/Array URL published externally).